# Real estate vs property tags -- same thing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As far as I can tell, every [property](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/property) question could be in [real-estate](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-estate) instead (some have both). All of the questions so far use property to talk about real estate -- even though in theory property has a more general meaning, in the context of this site it is very likely that questions about property are about real estate.

I don't have rep on [real-estate](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-estate) to propose [property](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/property) as a synonym, but perhaps someone who does feels like this might be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Great idea -- this is done, and the synonym is all set up.